# What type of variable that contain lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Can you explain which type of `L` in this context.
In other words what type I can use instead `auto` keyword?

```
int main(){
 int x=0;
 auto L = [x] (int y)->bool{
   return x>y;
 };
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's a unique, unnamed type.

Comment: Nothing; `auto` is the only way to get an exactly-typed object, though you can store a lambda in a callable-holder such as `std::function<>`.

Comment: @ildjarn `decltype(auto)` works too ;)

Comment: @T.C. : Fair enough. :-P

Comment: @T.C. Tagged C++11...

Comment: @ildjarn: You can pass a lambda to `template<typename T> void foo(T)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing in C++11 which you could use instead of `auto` in this context that would mean the exact same type. That's because the type of each lambda expression is a unique, unnamed type. Quoting C++11 5.1.2/3:

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union
>   class type — called the *closure type* — whose properties are described below. ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::function` instead of `auto, but you may not want to.

[This article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1859) explains in more detail:

> The basic principle behind auto is that the compiler knows the type …
>   but you either can’t describe it or don’t want to. There is one
>   primary use-case where you cannot name the type – with lambdas.

The article then notes how you can use a std::function instead, but with a run-time penalty.